# assigning 'points' to array based on position, how to deal with ties?

Tags: php

I have an array filled with arrays with a name, then a gross amount. This array is then being assigned a "points total" based on their gross ranking. The points decreases by 2 with every rank, but my issue is how can i deal with ties? Ideally i'd see how many ties, add up the total points for those rankings, then divide it by how many are tied, but i have no clue how to really accomplish that

Here is my array usort:

```
function grossSort($gross, $compare) {
    if($gross['gross'] > $compare['gross'])
        return -1; // move up
    else if($gross['gross'] < $compare['gross'])
        return 1; // move down
    else
        return 0; // do nothing
}
```

turns my array into this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [instr] => lee
            [gross] => 2094
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [instr] => steve
            [gross] => 1334
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [instr] => nick
            [gross] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [instr] => amber
            [gross] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [instr] => lindsey
            [gross] => 0
        )

)
```

And here's what im doing to assign points now:

```
$maxpoints = 40;            
for($i = 0; $i < count($trainergross); $i++){
    $trainergross[$i]['points'] += $maxpoints;
    $maxpoints -=2;
}
```

and now my array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [instr] => lee
            [gross] => 2094
            [points] => 40
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [instr] => steve
            [gross] => 1334
            [points] => 38
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [instr] => nick
            [gross] => 0
            [points] => 36
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [instr] => amber
            [gross] => 0
            [points] => 34
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [instr] => lindsey
            [gross] => 0
            [points] => 32
        )

)
```

And here's my issue, there are 4 people "tied" but getting decreasing points, I have no clue how to address this in the current way my code is set up. Anyone have any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the last known value as you iterate, and only decrease the points when the value changed. The array is sorted, so the equal elements will be adjacent.

```
/**
 * award average of points to a number of elements.
 * @param arrayref $trainergross - reference to the original array
 * @param int $award - total points to award
 * @param int $start_index - which element to start with?
 * @param int $count - how many elements should be awarded points?
 * @return void
 */
function award_points(&$trainergross, $award, $start_index, $count=1)
{
    if(!$count || $award<1) return; // if noone is waiting for the award, OR there is no award, bail out

    // $awards holds total award, and we need to
    $avgPoints = $award / $count;

    // award points to $count previous elements
    for($j = $start_index; $j < $start_index + $count; ++$j)
    {
        // in case points key was not initialized, php will issue a notice.
        if(!isset($trainergross[$j]['points'])) $trainergross[$j]['points'] = 0;

        $trainergross[$j]['points'] += $avgPoints;
    }
}

/**
 * This is increased on purpose
 * the first check will be <some number> vs null, which will result in -=2.
 * this is to eliminate additional !== null test inside the loop.
 */
$maxpoints = 42;

// This will be used to store number of consecutive elements
$count = 0;

// This will be used to store total points to award
$award = 0;

// Here we will store last gross value
$last = null;

for($i = 0; $i < count($trainergross); $i++)
{
    $maxpoints -= 2;

    // if gross has not changed, just count consecutive elements and continue
    if($last == $trainergross[$i]['gross'])
    {
        $award += $maxpoints;
        $count++;
        continue;
    }

    // store gross value
    $last = $trainergross[$i]['gross'];

    // now really distribute the points we've gathered in award by now
    award_points($trainergross, $award, $i - $count, $count);

    // reset count back to 1 (there is only 1 "consecutive" element now)
    $count = 1;

    // next element will get this award
    $award = $maxpoints;
}

// now we have to award points again
// the loop ended, but $count of elements are still awaiting points...
award_points($trainergross, $award, $i - $count, $count);
```

Comment: you may also want to decrease the value by factor of equal elements sequence length... in which case you'd need another temp variable to keep track of that length (and revert it to 1 once the gross value changes).

Comment: This will not assign an average point value to all consecutive elements.

Comment: @Joel you are correct, but this returns much better results than i was getting before. Still going to try to figure out the average though.

Comment: actually, if you make average, then person ranked lower would get more points than each of the tied ones... But you're right Joel, i missed that part when i read the Q ;)

Comment: @poncha 3, 4, 5 should all get 34 points (average of 36, 34, 32) then 6th place should get 30. I however cannot think of a scenario where that would produce a different final ranking than giving 3,4,5 36 then 34 to 6th, so i think i would be safe to use your solution

Comment: you could store pointers to the sequence elements (in an array) instead of just the last gross number - and then apply the points to all the referenced elements once the value has changed, if that is really needed.

Comment: @robz228 I have a working version now.. waiting for the edit to be reviewed. It was close, I just wasn't handling the case of the last element being a duplicate.

Comment: ok, i've edited the solution now, since @Joel's edit did not get through yet. cleaned up and moved the code that really awards points into separate function as it is getting used twice. on your sample data this code produces the following set of points: 40, 38, 34, 34, 34

Comment: @Joel btw there was a problem with average calculation - making just `- $count` does not really produce average... on this sample data, three last elements would get 33 rather than 34 points (since it's 36 max minus 3 elements in count).

Comment: @poncha Actually, it does work because $count = 2 on the third double. Count isnt incremented until we have found a double. Let n = count, x = max points. Then average = (x + (x - 2*n)) / 2 = (2x - 2n) / 2 = x - n.  However, there was a problem with how i was decrementing the maxcount after calculating the average.

Comment: @poncha this is great, works amazing. thanks for all the noting too so i can truly understand it!  here is my final peice of code if interested: http://pastebin.com/PiucYMM3

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the fact that the scores are sorted; for every iteration, you try to find as many equal scores as possible and then update the whole batch in one go:

```
$trainergross = [
    ['instr' => 'lee', 'gross' => 2094],
    ['instr' => 'steve', 'gross' => 1334],
    ['instr' => 'nick', 'gross' => 0],
    ['instr' => 'amber', 'gross' => 0],
    ['instr' => 'lindsay', 'gross' => 0],
];

$maxpoints = 40;

for ($current = 0; $current < count($trainergross); $current = $next) {
    // find the first unequal score and reduce points to calculate average later
    $next = $current; $minpoints = $maxpoints;
    while (++$next < count($trainergross) && $trainergross[$next]['gross'] == $trainergross[$current]['gross']) {
      $minpoints -= 2;
    }

    if ($minpoints == $maxpoints) {
        $trainergross[$current]['points'] = $maxpoints;
    } else {
        // tie, calculate average points to award
        $points = floor(($maxpoints + $minpoints) / 2);

        // update this batch
        for ($i = $current; $i < $next; ++$i) {
            $trainergross[$i]['points'] = $points;
        }
    }

    // decrease the points for next iteration
    $maxpoints = $minpoints - 2;
}

print_r($trainergross);
```

Comment: the consecutive elements should be awarded *average* of points they would get in total if each had a decrease of two... eg on this sample data, they should get 40,38,34,34,34 (last three elements should have got 36,34,32 which results in average of 34)

Comment: I did too, at first ;)

Comment: @poncha It's updated and should work, but I'm not entirely happy with the control structures =(